# Como usar ViewSet para retornar templates en django

Tags: django

soy nuevo en python, he revisado como funcionan las vistas basadas en clases pero me parece tedioso el tener una vista generica para cada accion por ejemplo para sacar el listado uso ListView, para crear uso el CreateView y asi.

```
class CrearUsuarioView(CreateView):
model = User
template_name = 'user/create_form.html'
form_class = CrearUsuarioForm

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if not request.is_ajax():
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("<h1>{}</h1>".format("Bad Request"))
    form = CrearUsuarioForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success', 'message': 'Guardado correctamente'})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'error_list': form.errors})


class EditarUsuario(UpdateView):
model = User
template_name = 'user/form.html'
context_object_name = 'data'
form_class = EditarUsuarioForm

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    data['pageUrl'] = "/general/usuarios"
    data['pageModule'] = "usuarios"
    return data

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_user = User.objects.get(pk=kwargs.get('pk'))
    user_form = EditarUsuarioForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=form_user)
    if user_form.is_valid():
        user_form.save(request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success', 'message': 'Los cambios fueron guardados correctamente.'})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'error_list': user_form.errors})



class ListadoUsuarios(ListView):
paginate_by = 10
template_name = 'user/index.html'
model = User

def get_queryset(self):
    search = self.request.GET.get('s', '')
    if search != '':
        object_list = self.model.objects.filter(
            Q(username__icontains=search) | Q(first_name__icontains=search) | Q(last_name__icontains=search) | Q(
                email__icontains=search)).order_by('username')
    else:
        object_list = self.model.objects.all().order_by('username')
    return object_list

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    data['pageTitle'] = _('Listado de Usuarios')
    data['pageNote'] = _('Mostrando todos los registros')
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')
    data['list_display'] = list_display
    return data
```

Las urls las tengo de esta forma pero me gustaria tener solo una que contenga todos los metodos crud algo similar a como trabaja Laravel a traves de Route::resource('users') crearia todos los metodos create, update, destroy, show

```
path('usuarios/<int:pk>/edit', EditarUsuario.as_view()),
path('usuarios/create', CrearUsuarioView.as_view()),
```

Me interesa tener una sola vista que simplifique el tener que usar todas estas vistas genericas, he leido un poco al respecto y parece ser que ViewSet es la solucion pero esto me propociona una API y no logro retornar los render con los templates respectivos en el caso de crear por ejemplo.

Comment: Que has intentado, puedes mostrarnos tu código? así podremos ayudarte mejor

Comment: @GermanAlzate he actualizado la pregunta junto con el codigo que he intentado

Comment: El problema es que son dos funcionalidades completamente distintas ya que crear un objeto nuevo tiene un proceso y actualizarlo primero tienes que obtener el objeto creado previamente. Lo que si puedes es tener el mismo template para ambas cosas y redirigir a la funcionalidad que quieras.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar Django rest Framework 
aqui hay un ejemplo 
https://godjango.com/41-start-your-api-django-rest-framework-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

De poder gestionar todo en una misma vista se puede hacer, Yo por lo general para crear, actualizar y eliminar uso una sola vista, heredando de "UpdateView". Todo depende de que es lo que necesitas. Si quieres aprender mas como funciona internamente las vistas basadas en clase te invito a que mires los diferentes archivos del repositorio ["django/views/generic"](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/views/generic)